# How to insert an object into an object with nlohmann json library

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I am unable to insert a JSON object into another object using c++ library “nlohmann json”. An array is inserted instead of an object. [I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffc7X.png)    [And it turns out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFTfE.png)

The code I am using:
`playersSkins.push_back(json::object_t::value_type(playerName, {"color", "#000"}));`

Comment: You can use very close to actual json syntax with nlohmann json.
`nlohmann_json::json j = {{"player": {"color": "#000"}}}`

Comment: But that's the wrong syntax. https://skr.sh/sFft40Dhvnt

Comment: Whoops. Try `nlohmann_json::json j = {{"player", {"color", "#000"}}}`

Comment: All the same. Instead of an object - an array

Answer (score 2):

Per documentation on [`nlohmann::json::object()`](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/object/), the initializer list needs to contain pairs for it to be treated as an object. Otherwise it will be treated as an array.

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    nlohmann::json playerSkins;
    std::string playerName = "player";
    playerSkins.push_back({{playerName, {{"color", "#000"}}}});;
    std::cout << playerSkins.dump() << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
[{"player":{"color":"#000"}}]
```

https://godbolt.org/z/n73oKxshe

Comment: I wanted an object to be created for each player. as I understand it, to create an object, you need double brackets. If so then my code should look like this https://skr.sh/sFfX1wrfdWT. But it doesn't compile

Comment: @Er2n You're missing the double brackets around the player name and color object like I have in my example. `push_back` takes a single argument but you're passing two. `playerSkins.push_back({{playerName, {{...}}}});` not `playerSkins.push_back(playerName, {{...}});`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my last post. I wanted to write that I would not like the object to be created for each player.

Comment: @Er2n I'm not sure I follow. Do you not want `playerSkins` to be an array? If that's the case then you want to do `playerSkins[playerName] = {{"color", "#000"}};` instead. Calling `playerSkins.push_back` makes `playerSkins` into an array.